# Linkedin - Exchange Authorization Code for a Request Token

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I'm trying to exchange auth code for request token using linkedin API. However I try I always getting error:

> { ["error_description"]=> string(107) "missing required parameters,
>   includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. :
>   client_secret" ["error"]=> string(15) "invalid_request" }

My code looks like:

```
 public function authorization($authCode)
    {
        //define enviroment and path
        $host = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken";

        // Generate urlencode data
        $data_string = 'grant_type=authorization_code';
        $data_string .= '&code='.$authCode;
        $data_string .= '&redirect_uri='.redirectUrl;
        $data_string .= '&client_id='.publicKey;
        $data_string .= '&client_secret'.secretKey;
        var_dump($data_string);


        // set up the curl resource
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        ));

        // execute the request
        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        //echo($output) . PHP_EOL;
        $output = json_decode($output);
        var_dump($output);

        echo $output->access_token;

        // close curl resource to free up system resources
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

simple calling of fuction is like:

```
if(!empty($_GET['code']))
{
    $state = $_GET['state'];
    $authCode = $_GET['code'];
    $LinkedIn->authorization($authCode);
}
```

I try to make this REQUEST using my data via postman and I get Access token succesfully so I have some bug here which I can't see.

Is here anyone who can advise me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to put an 'equal to' sign after client_secret

```
$data_string .= '&client_id='.publicKey;
$data_string .= '&client_secret='.secretKey;
var_dump($data_string);
```

Comment: And put a `$` before the variable's name, otherwise they will be interpreted as constants

Comment: Hi Federico they are constants this is okey, however i feel really lame to miss that 'equal to' . Thank you @littlebex

Comment: it does, I'm still waiting for timer to enable me "Accept" this answer as correct